# Button add as sub view in table view showing in other cells also

Tags: iphone, object, user-interface, location

I have table view and in section second's row I have placed a button, when I scroll the table view this button appear in other rows too.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];/////self...ramesh
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kCellID];
    }

    if (indexPath.row==1)
    {
        cell.accessoryView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.warmUpSwitch.frame];
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Warm Up(5 min.)";
        [cell.accessoryView addSubview:self.warmUpSwitch];
    }
    if (indexPath.row==2)
    {
        cell.accessoryView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.coolDownSwitch.frame];

        cell.textLabel.text=@"Cool Down(5 min.)";
        [cell.accessoryView addSubview:self.coolDownSwitch];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code, I doubt you are using reusability for all cells and getting buttons for unwanted cells as well

Comment: Althought it's not a good approach but setting reusable identifier to nil will help you.

Comment: please post your code how you have added button

Comment: i have added code now please check this .

Comment: Can you post entire method how cell init and all ?

Comment: actually i have 4 section in table view and in last section i have button and text field ,more over this table view is long list of items ,so i think when i scroll down its not removing the textfield and utton and this appearin in new cells ,if this is correct thinking than please suggest the good approach .

Comment: using storyboard and customcell ?

Comment: i am not using story board

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


}
  if (indexPath.row==1)
    {

     UIButton *btnwarmUpSwitch = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
     btnwarmUpSwitch.frame = CGRectMake(250,20,100,50);  //set frame where you want to set
    [btnwarmUpSwitch setTitle:@"Warm Up(5 min.)" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     btnwarmUpSwitch.tag=indexPath.row;
    [btnwarmUpSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(selectwarmUpSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:btnwarmUpSwitch];


    }
    if (indexPath.row==2)
    {
        UIButton *btncoolDownSwitch = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
     btncoolDownSwitch.frame = CGRectMake(250,20,100,50);  //set frame where you want to set
    [btncoolDownSwitch setTitle:@"Cool Down(5 min.)" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     btncoolDownSwitch.tag=indexPath.row;
    [btncoolDownSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(selectcoolDownSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:btncoolDownSwitch];
    }
   return cell;
 }
 - (void) selectwarmUpSwitch:(id)sender
 {

 }
 - (void) selectcoolDownSwitch:(id)sender
 {

 }
```

Comment: i do changes but this problen of overshowing text field and switch in text fiels stilll.please tell me the benifit of using tag,means textfield.tag.

Comment: One more condition is also there might be helpful ,i have added table view as a sub view  and over it i added the button and text field ,might be this thing not clearing the reusebility of cell